# React Native in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-2017

Has anyone tried building a React Native project in Visual Studio 2017?

Every resource I find points to Visual Studio Code but no mention of Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is optimized for developing modern web apps. This will be why it features heavily. Visual Studio is much more focused on Desktop/Mobile compiled applications & games using C#, C++. That's certainly not to say it's not possible, it might require a little more digging to get started.

Comment: Any positive movement on this one? (after a year and 6 months)

Comment: @Sam: It is 3 years later and I am wondering whether you could share the resources you talked about, namely how to use React Native with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @B--rian Just checked my VS Code config and looks like the only extension I added is the `React Native Tools` which you can install thru the Extensions tab in VS Code. I also had to install `Android Studio` and run it while I develop so that I can use the emulator. I also use Chrome to debug. HTH

Comment: @Sam Thanks for your lines. I guess I will ask a separate question about that Android-Studio issue, whether I really need it. Otherwise I guess you are talking about https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native are you?

Comment: @B--rian I'm pretty sure you do need the Android Studio (AS). At the very least, you need the emulator so that you can test your code and see what the app looks like on a phone/tablet. But I'm sure there's more to it than that. There's a whole bunch of stuff that are seemingly in the background for you to be able to develop for Android platform and I suspect some of them are installed with AS. When I develop, I simply go into AS and start the emulator and close AS. From that point on, I'm only using VS Code for writing my code, Chrome for debugging and the emulator for seeing the results.

Comment: React Native Tools (RNT) -- the link you mentioned in your comments -- are there to make writing React Native code easier in VS Code, such as understanding `JSX`. As you know, out of the box, VS Code has no idea about React Native. This is true of developing in other technologies as well. For example, I don't think out of the box, VS Code knows anything about `Java`. If you're a `Java` developer, you'd add a few extensions to make writing `Java` code easier and more fun in VS Code. HTH

Comment: Wanted to mention another specific case where I actually must keep AS running while developing in React Native and that's when I want my RN code to hit the local instance of my API app. This is a case when a `localhost` is hitting another `localhost`. This requires some network handling and AS has the ability to do this. If my RN app is hitting my API on the Internet, I don't need this but if I want it to hit the local instance, AS has to be running during the entire `debug` session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seems as MS has no plans to support React Native in their flagship - only in VS Code. 
Vote in the Forum...

[MS Forum to VS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/10362174-add-react-native-support-to-vs2015)