# Is it possible to create react-native project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, react-native

[React Native in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813966/react-native-in-visual-studio-2017)
It's been 2 years, anything new? I'm trying to create react-native on Visual Studio 2017 and NOT Visual Studio Code. Is it possible? Since I'm familiar with Team Foundation on VS, and I've no clue about Team Foundation on VS CODE.

Comment: No, and I don't see why Visual Studio would ever consider adding native support to React Native development inside their IDE (due to limitations such as iOS simulator only working on OSX, Android Studio and xCode being available, etc.). The best you're gonna get is most likely syntax highlighting and code completion through plugins/extensions.

Comment: you can use notepad ++ too if you want or also you can use simeple notepad or sublime text edito

Comment: Can't we do it in gedit or nano, lol..!! @MayankPandav

Comment: yes we can create own editor too

Comment: yes you can use notebook as well