# Can I run react-native project on Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, npm, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to open and run react-native project on Visual Studio 2017?

**Steps:**

1. Open VS 2017
2. File open folder{react-native project folder}
3. On VS2017 terminal, type `react-native run-android`

But the Android simulator keeps loading with no error. 
I want to use team foundation function, so I’m trying to run react-native on VS2017

Comment: Did emulator show anything ? Or black screen

Comment: White screen with loading spinner

Comment: Did you try to wipe data on the emulator and turn it off and turn on ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813966/react-native-in-visual-studio-2017)